# Refresh asp.net mvc web page automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i want to refresh  my web page automatically in 30 second, but without blink.Here
I am using asp.net mvc framework. Can u help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**meta** tag is what I would suggest using:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Your requirement "without blink" is not trivial if even possible. Just remember, if user's computer is slow the refresh may be sluggish. You have no control over it.

Comment: maybe without blink means by ajax...?

Comment: aha! the whole page without blink... sounds like web 3.0. LOL

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `AJAX` to update the information you need to instead of forcing the whole page to reload as it would be quicker and less confusing for the user. Also, it would provide the "without blink" feature you asked for.

Comment: I didn't see your comment before writing my answer.